dllnotfoundexception when trying to use native with android .net 8.0
I was trying to build a simple solution in android .net 8.0 using ndk. but the .so file has not referenced getting an exception DLLNotFoundException. Eventhough all .so files are placed in lib folder under each abi. Comments and answers are welcome!
I have tried placing .so file in various places but still getting DLLNotFoundException
